# radioButtons works only in the second chance in shiny app R

Tags: r, shiny

I'm developing a mechanism in Shiny to allow the user to select the type of dataset they want to load (either .xlsx or .txt). For this, I configured the radioButtons function to provide the selection option and created a conditional function that checks the choice made to use the appropriate reading function. However, when the mechanism is executed for the first time, it doesn't return anything; it only works correctly when I switch to the other option and load the file again. What could be happening for it to fail initially but work when the option is changed in radioButtons?

Thanks in advance.

This is my R code:

```
library(shiny); library(data.table); library(readxl)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons(inputId = "input_radio", label = p("Choose type of dataset:"), choices  = list("Excel (.xlsx)" = 1L, "Text (.txt)" = 2L), selected = 0L),
      uiOutput("input_excel"),
      uiOutput("input_txt"),
      actionButton(inputId = "start_buttom", label = "Check input structure")
    ),
    mainPanel(dataTableOutput("table_dataset"))
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$input_excel <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(input$input_radio)){
      return()
    } else if(input$input_radio == 1L){
      fileInput(inputId = 'dataset_excel', label = 'Select file:')
    }
  })
  
  output$input_txt <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(input$input_radio)){
      return()
    } else if(input$input_radio == 2L){
      fileInput(inputId = 'dataset_txt', label = 'Select file:')
    }
  })
  
  datasetInput <- eventReactive(input$start_buttom, {
    req(input$dataset_excel, input$dataset_txt, input$input_radio)
    aux <- input$input_radio

    if(aux == 1L){
      data <- input$dataset_excel; dataset <- read_xlsx(data$datapath)
    } else if(aux == 2L) {
      data <- input$dataset_txt; dataset <- fread(data$datapath)
    }
    return(dataset)
  })
  
  output$table_dataset <- renderDataTable({datasetInput()})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I'm not familiar with shiny, so i've try different functions to do that and this is my best solution at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have the line

```
req(input$dataset_excel, input$dataset_txt, input$input_radio)
```

which means that values are required for both the excel file and the txt file. That doesn't seem to be what you really want. I assume you want only one to be present. If you take out that line, you should be able to display the table without toggling the radio button.

I'm not sure why you have two different file input to begin with. You  could just as easily use

```
library(shiny); library(data.table); library(readxl)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons(inputId = "input_radio", label = p("Choose type of dataset:"), choices  = list("Excel (.xlsx)" = 1L, "Text (.txt)" = 2L), selected = 0L),
      fileInput(inputId = 'dataset_file', label = 'Select file:'),
      actionButton(inputId = "start_buttom", label = "Check input structure")
    ),
    mainPanel(dataTableOutput("table_dataset"))
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  datasetInput <- eventReactive(input$start_buttom, {
    req(input$dataset_file, input$input_radio)
    aux <- input$input_radio
    
    data <- input$dataset_file
    dataset <- if(aux == 1L) {
      read_xlsx(data$datapath)
    } else if(aux == 2L) {
      fread(data$datapath)
    }
    return(dataset)
  })
  
  output$table_dataset <- renderDataTable({datasetInput()})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, 

I am developing both options because I intend to accommodate two types of data input, one that considers a file on the local hard drive (.xlsx) using the fileInput, and a second one that will be the name of a database view that I will receive through a textInput as a parameter.

I tried to provide an example with the .xlsx and .txt files because I believe it would be easier to illustrate what happens. I've posted even using the textInput the error continues.

Comment: You still have the problem if you remove the `req()`? Then I cannot reproduce the issue given your description. Can you be more explicitly about what exactly you are doing/running and what the output is?

Comment: In the initial development, I noticed that req() was mandatory to update the "id" of radioButtons. But now, following your suggestion to remove it, I noticed that the previous bug has been resolved. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use one `fileInput` as that can take any file format. You only need to use some conditional functions when it comes to reading the file in - i.e. when you use `input$<id>$datapath` and you can use `tools::file_ext` to check the format, rather than needing the user to select the format.

Something like this works:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    fileInput("file", "Upload file")
)

server <- function(input, output){

    df <- reactive({
      req(input$file)
      file_format <- tools::file_ext(input$file$datapath[1])
      if (file_format == "txt"){
        df <- fread(input$file$datapath[1])
      } else if (file_format == "xlsx"){
        df <- openxlsx::read.xlsx(input$file$datapath[1])
      }
    })
   }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks @smatse,

I would like the first input option to be a local file (.xlsx), and the second option to be a view name passed as a text parameter via textInput, which I will read through R. In this case i think that tools::file_ext doesn't works.